# Can I have Xcode sign MacOS binary AdHoc with entitlement to enable coredumps?

Tags: macos, xcode, code-signing

I want to enable coredumps for a locally used MacOS binary. I'd like Xcode to sign the binary appropriately.

Currently I need to run the following two commands after the binary is generated to enable core dumps:

```
% /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Add :com.apple.security.get-task-allow bool true" tmp.entitlements
% codesign -s - -f --entitlements tmp.entitlements MyBinary
```

My org doesn't distribute enough mac binaries to request "developer credentials". I just want to see a coredump on the machine where a binary was compiled.

How can I make Xcode do this for me?

Answer (score 1):

## Custom Build Scripts

You can add a custom build script step to your Xcode workflow, see [Running custom scripts during a build](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/running-custom-scripts-during-a-build):

> To execute a custom script at build time, add a Run Script build phase to your target. This build phase runs separately from the target’s other build phases, such as the compilation and link build phases. You may add multiple script-related build phases to your target to execute scripts at different stages of the build.
>
> To add a Run Script build phase to a target:
>
> 1. In the project navigator, select your project.
> 2. Select the target you want to modify.
> 3. Click the Build Phases tab.
> 4. Click the Add button (+), then choose “New Run Script Phase” from the pop-up menu.
> 5. Click the disclosure triangle for the newly added Run Script phase.
> 6. In the Shell text field, enter your script code.